# Covariance matrix and vec operation

Tags: variance, covariance, matrix, linear-algebra

I have the following matrix:

$ U  = \begin{bmatrix}u_{1} \\ u_{2}  \\ \vdots \\u_{T} 
 \end{bmatrix}$

where $u_i$ are $k \times N $ matrices and

$E[vec (u_i) vec (u_i)'] = \Sigma_i \otimes I_k $

for $i=1, \ldots,T$ and $I_k$ is the $k \times k$ identity matrix. The $\Sigma_i$ matrices look like:

$\Sigma_i = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{11,i}  &  \ldots & \sigma_{1N ,i}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\  \sigma_{N1,i} & \ldots & \sigma_{NN,i}\end{bmatrix}$

The correlation between the elements in $u_i, u_j$ is zero for $i\neq j$ and $i,j=1, \ldots, T$ and also $E[u_i]= 0_{k\times N}$

How can I obtain an expression of $ E[vec(U)vec(U)'] $ as a function of all the $\Sigma_i$ with $i = 1,\ldots, T$ matrices? For example, by putting all the $\Sigma_i$ in a big block diagonal matrix or in general defining another big matrix that contains all the $\Sigma_i$?

Comment: It seems to be that this would require knowing sth. about how the $u_i$ are related to each other. Are they uncorrelated?

Comment: Yes you are right I forgot to mention. They are unocorrelated

Comment: You need to specify the expectations, too, but your language suggests you assume those are all zero.  If not, please tell us what your assumption is.  Apart from that I don't see there is anything that needs answering here, because you already specify the expectation of the products in terms of the $\Sigma_i$ matrices.  Are you perhaps looking to write that down in some different form?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes the expectations are all zero. I am looking for $E[vec(U)vec(U)′]$ as a function of all the $\Sigma_i$ for $i =1, \ldots,T$ matrices, while right now I have just the variance-covariance matrices for the subvectors $E[vec(u_i)vec(u_i)′]$ as a function of each $\Sigma_i$.

Comment: Yes, in this sense I am looking for a different (matrix) formulation, which involves all the $\Sigma_i$ since I need $E[vec(U)vec(U)′]$ for other calculations.

Comment: For example, by putting all the $\Sigma_i$ in a big block diagonal matrix. Or in general defining another big matrix that contains all the $\Sigma_i$

Comment: That's really just a programming issue whose solution depends on the capabilities of the programming environment you are using.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it is a just a programming issue, since I actually don't know, and it is what I am asking, how to obtain $E[vec(U)vec(U)']$ as a function of all the $\Sigma_i$ matrices. Could you suggest me one way?